# What is "Unix Mailspool (Movemail)"?

Tags: thunderbird, maildir

Thunderbird only offers to create another account in the format "Unix Mailspool (Movemail)".

What is this format? It looks different from "Maildir".

Comment: How to set it up:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/301988/using-movemail-with-thunderbird-on-ubuntu/1103958#1103958

Answer (score 2):

I found some hints:

> https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird:Pluggable_Mail_Stores#Current_Mail_Store
>
> Currently, local mailboxes and offline news& IMAP stores use the berkeley mailbox format, a flat file in the [Mbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) family

and

> http://whatis.techtarget.com/fileformat/MBOX-Mailbox-file-Berkeley-Unix
>
> ### MBOX File Format
>
> **Mailbox file (Berkeley Unix)**
>
> MBOX is a file extension for a text file used to organize and store
>   e-mail messages. MBOX stands for MailBOX.
>
> The MBOX file is the most common format for storing email messages on
>   a hard drive. All the messages for each mailbox are stored as a
>   single, long, text file in a string of concatenated e-mail messages,
>   starting with the “From” header of the message. MBOX files were used
>   predominantly on Unix. MBOX files are still used with several current
>   e-mail clients, including Mozilla Thunderbird, Microsoft Entourage and
>   Qualcomm Eudora.

If you look in

```
preference -> advanced -> general -> config editor
```

and search for `msgstore` you find

```
mail.serverDefaultStoreContractID = "@mozilla.org/msgstore/berekeleystore;1″
```